# Dynamic type-hint in Laravel for Form Request

Tags: php, laravel

I've created a Base Controller and I want to dynamically type-hint the store method to use the proper Form Request class. How can I do that?

Here's my base controller (simplified):

```php
class BaseController extends Controller
{
  protected $baseClass;
  protected $baseResourceClass;
  protected $baseStoreRequestClass;

  public function index()
  {
     $items = $baseClass::paginate(10);
     return $baseResourceClass::collection($items);
  }

  // the $baseStoreRequestClass doesn't work, and that's what I'm trying to figure it out
  public function store(**$baseStoreRequestClass** $request)
  {
     $validatedFields = $request->validated();
     $newItem = $baseClass::create($validatedFields);
     return new $baseResourceClass($newItem);
  }
}
```

Then, from the controller that will extend, I would have just to declare the 3 variables. Example:

```php
class UserController extends BaseController
{
  protected $baseClass = '\App\User';
  protected $baseResourceClass = '\App\Http\Resources\UserResource';
  protected $baseStoreRequestClass = '\App\Http\Requests\StoreUser';
}

class ProductController extends BaseController
{
  protected $baseClass = '\App\Product';
  protected $baseResourceClass = '\App\Http\Resources\roductResource';
  protected $baseStoreRequestClass = '\App\Http\Requests\StoreProduct';
}
```

How could I make the **$baseStoreRequestClass** works?

Comment: you could create a BaseFormRequest and inherit your requests from it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify a dynamic type as a function parameter. It's just not valid PHP syntax. Here's what I suggest. Your base class would be the boilerplate:

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
  protected $baseClass;
  protected $baseResourceClass;

  public function index()
  {
     $items = $baseClass::paginate(10);
     return $baseResourceClass::collection($items);
  }

  public function store(FormRequest $request) // Or other base request object you might create
  {
     $validatedFields = $request->validated();
     $newItem = $baseClass::create($validatedFields);
     return new $baseResourceClass($newItem);
  }
}
```

Then each subclassed controller would need an explicit request type:

```
class UserController extends BaseController
{
  protected $baseClass = '\App\User';
  protected $baseResourceClass = '\App\Http\Resources\UserResource';
  public function store(StoreUser $request) {
      return parent::store($request);
  }
}
```

Comment: Super!! That works perfectly and solves my issue!! It's a very clean solution!! Thank you!!